# how to use awk's $0 variables in the shell file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

1.my shell file is

```
 [root@node3 script]# cat hi.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 strings="sdsf sdsda sdsadx"
 echo `awk "{print substr($0,0,9)}"<<<$strings`
```

2.exe my shell file

```
[root@node3 script]# sh hi.sh 

awk: {print substr(hi.sh,0,9)}

awk:                 ^ syntax error

awk: 致命错误: 0 是 substr 的无效参数个数
```

so how to use the awk's $0 in shell file ?

the $0 default file's name .

another ques. i want use the var $0 about awk but the another $variable in the shell file.what should i do ?

```
$ cat hi.sh 
#!/bin/bash 
strings="sdsf sdsda sdsadx" 
num=9 
echo \`awk '{print substr($0,0,$num)}' <<< $strings\`
```

Comment: what do you want as a result?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i got the answer.thanks anyway

Comment: for second question, don't put it here. Look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) . If still you are not able to figure it out, ask a different question.

Comment: `echo $(foo)` is pointless; just use `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your script is use of double quotes in awk. Replace them with single quotes.

When you use double quotes, the `$0` inside it is treated as first argument to the script, which in this case is script name `hi.sh`. If you use single quotes, you can use `$0` as `awk` argument to display whole row.

Also `echo` is not needed here, you can just use `awk '{print substr($0,0,9)}' <<< $strings`

```
$ cat hi.sh
#!/bin/bash
strings="sdsf sdsda sdsadx"
#echo `awk '{print substr($0,0,9)}' <<< $strings` --echo not needed
awk '{print substr($0,0,9)}' <<< $strings
$
$ sh hi.sh
sdsf sdsd
```

Comment: i replaced and it worked.  thanks u. ps: your code on the web still show double quotes .

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: Yes, mentioned that in the answer as well. I just wanted to point the error in OP's query, hence kept the rest of the code as it is.

Comment: in `awk` there is an option to define variable outside like `awk var=$num ....` then use can use `$var` inside awk. Not exactly sure on the command so better to do a google search :)

Comment: i kown what u say .use the awk's variable to solve it .